# date.timezone PHP error

Tags: php5, timezone

I'm getting the infamous PHP timezone error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: It is not
>   safe to rely on the system's timezone
>   settings. You are *required* to use
>   the date.timezone setting or the
>   date_default_timezone_set() function.
>   In case you used any of those methods
>   and you are still getting this
>   warning, you most likely misspelled
>   the timezone identifier. We selected
>   'Europe/Moscow' for 'MSK/3.0/no DST'
>   instead in Unknown on line 0

I did use date.timezone indeed, setting it to Europe/Berlin and Europe/Vilnius and then 'Europe/Vilnius' in php.ini but nothing seems to work.

Using PHP 5.3.0 with Apache 2 server on Ubuntu Linux 9.04

Besides, I'm getting this error at the time Apache with PHP starts, it is probably caused by one of plugins, maybe pecl... anyway, how could I set that timezone properly? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working after complete apache & php reinstall from source. Must have been some LAMPP bug, probably.

Answer (score 1):

On a per-script basis without using php.ini (extra useful if it was shared hosting), include this in a header or wherever relevant:

```
<?php
echo date_default_timezone_get(); //Before
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s T'); //After
?>
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about where you are making that setting?  The OP specifically mentions php.ini so he can set this globally.  Would be a great answer if it had a little more explanation.

Comment: Fixed and yeah; it isn't global but it's a practical solution but not permanent.